# Can you use oracle table spaces like variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am new to Oracle, I have two tablespaces one for dev and one for live.

Is there a way that I can have a variable on a Package header that contains a tablespace name, which can then be used from within the procedures defined in the package header?

I need to do this as I have one tableSpace (TableSpaceA) that needs to query tables in TableSpaceB via procedures.  The Dev TableSpaceB has a different table space name to live therefore I was hoping I could declare in the Package header a variable like

`Tablespace temp = "TableSpaceName"`

Then

`Select * from temp.TableName`

And finally change "TableSpaceName" when i roll my changes out to the live environment?

Comment: Do you mean "schema" rather than "tablespace"?

Comment: Well PL/SQL displays them as tablespaces, so I presume tablespace and not schema???

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "PL/SQL displays them as tablespaces..."  PL/SQL is a language, not a display tool??  But you clearly DO mean "schema" and not "tablespace".

Comment: Yeah I meant PLSQL Developer missed out a word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tablespaces are an administrative thing: they are a way of logically grouping storage without the need to worry about filepaths or other administrivia.

---

From your revised question it is obvious that Tony is right and what you mean is *schema*.

A schema is the set of objects owned by a user.  When a procedure owned by User A needs to reference an object owned by Schema B there are two ways of doing this.  The first way is to hardcode the schema name.

```
select * 
from user_b.emp;
```

This is usually fine but will not work in the scenario you describe, where the other schema has a different name different name in other environments (C rather than B).

The way around this problem is to use synonyms.

```
select * 
from not_my_emp;
```

In DEV the synonym would be:

```
create synonym not_my_emp for user_b.emp
/
```

whereas in production it would be

```
create synonym not_my_emp for user_c.emp
/
```

The table could even have a different table in production, it doesn't matter.  The synonym acts as an interface to shield our objects from the untidy details of other schemas.

Note that a synonym does not grant privileges on the underlying object.  This means that USER_B has to grant privileges on EMP in Development and USER_C has to grant privileges in Production.

Comment: Hi APC I have added some more detail for you in the original post

Comment: Yeah sure, I basically have two tablespaces, within one tablespace I have a package, which has a number of proceures.  In this tablespace I need to query a table in another tablespace which all seems to be working ok.  I wish to put these changes on to my live environment, but to do this I'd have to change the tablespace name that I am querying.  I appreciate your patients as you can tell oracle is very new to me

Comment: APC and Tony, thanks very much for your help this is exactly what I am looking for Thank you